# Different headers when requesting javascript from CDN vs locally

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

I'm maintaining an application that has some dialogs inserted dynamically. These dialogs often contain javascript that is loaded when the dialog appears, example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/charCount.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('#container').charCount(function() {
      /* more code here */
    });
});
```

Parent page has jquery already loaded, however the dialog adds a new javascript, which is charCount which adds a new method to jQuery.
This works fine, however, when we moved to a CDN so `charCount.js` is now loaded from there, I get `Incaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'charCount'` If I load the javascript locally, it works fine without any problems at all.

The only difference I see is how the javascript is being requested. When it's loaded locally, the request headers look like this:

```
Accept:text/javascript, application/javascript, application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=201217592.1524881892.1360801695.1367952052.1367956136.78; __utmb=201217592.2.9.1367956140967; __utmc=201217592; __utmz=201217592.1366916286.66.12.ut$
Host:localhost
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:localhost
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

When loading from CDN, the request headers look like this:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=201217592.1524881892.1360801695.1367952052.1367956136.78; __utmb=201217592.2.9.1367956140967; __utmc=201217592; __utmz=201217592.1366916286.66.12.
Host:<cdnurlhere>
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:localhost
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to load content using ajax. It will not work because it violates cross domain request policy. Simply speaking cross domain ajax requests are not allowed.

Comment: It's actually not an ajax call at all. Check my first code block, the only thing that changed was the `src` attribute.

Comment: Your top sample contains this header: X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest so I assumed it is XHR. If you just changed src attribute then it should work. Make sure JS file in the cloud has ContentType: application/javascript header set. That is your problem.